# ASP.NET Update Panel postback only by trigger

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to have the control inside the update panel not to cause a postback and update the control only by a trigger.
I have tried adding the tag "Triggers" but control is still updating after I do something on it.

```
<td>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel7" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <uc1:CBP runat="server" ID="C1" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="C2" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to make sure `ChildrenAsTriggers` property is set to `false`, otherwise your update panel can be triggered by its children as well as by defined triggers. Default of this property is `true`, which explains the behavior:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel7" runat="server"
                 UpdateMode="Conditional"
                 ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
```

This can also be found in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If the UpdateMode property is set to Conditional, and one of the
>   following conditions occurs: ... The ChildrenAsTriggers property is
>   set to true and a child control of the UpdatePanel control causes a
>   postback. A child control of a nested UpdatePanel control does not
>   cause an update to the outer UpdatePanel control unless it is
>   explicitly defined as a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you've set it up. If you have a Control that resides outside the update panels, that Control will do a postback to the entire page.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="smDefault" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlTime" runat="server" RenderMode="Block" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnInsideUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update from Inside" OnClick="btnInsideUpdate_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnInsideUpdate" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlOutside" runat="server" RenderMode="Block" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnOutsideUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update from outside" OnClick="btnOutsideUpdate_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnOutsideUpdate" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnUpdatePage" runat="server" Text="Update Page" OnClick="btnUpdatePage_Click" />
</div>
</form>
```

The btnInsideUpdate will update the contents of the updatepanel, as will the btnUpdatePage, however, the btnOutsideUpdate won't since that resides in Another update panel.